# In MongoDB, using Java how can I query to find documents exceeding 15 MB storage size in a database or collection

Tags: java, mongodb

In MongoDB, using Java how can I query to find documents which exceeds the 15mb  size in database or collection

Comment: Linux command is also fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { size: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } } },
   { $match: { size: { $gt: 15 * 1024 * 1024 } } }
])
```

Comment: This is working on version greater than 4.2, but for 4.0 this is throwing error called :- MongoServerError:- Unrecognised expression '$bsonSize'

Comment: Then you need a loop like this: `db.collection.find().forEach(x => print(Object.bsonsize(x)))`

Comment: Working perfectly Wernfried, Thankyou for support